# Insert into with conditional constant

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I wanted to make something like:

```
insert into Table(a, b, c)
select a, b, 1 from OtherTable
where a > 0
```

But where **c** would be a value of an Enum based on a certain condition of the where clause.

I wish the final result would be something similar to (even if this doesn't work):

```
insert into Table(a, b, c)
select a, b, x from OtherTable, YetAnotherTable
where a > 0 AND (IF a=b THEN x = 'Enum1' ELSE x = 'Enum2' ENDIF)
```

Do you think something like this is possible in a single statement?

Comment: Yes, there's no reason you can't do that.. If you provide your table structure and some sample data, you might get a more specific answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
insert into Table(a, b, c)
select a, 
       b, 
       CASE WHEN a = b THEN 'Enum1' ELSE 'Enum2' END
from OtherTable, YetAnotherTable
where a > 0
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: any idea why `IF a = b THEN 'Enum1' ELSE 'Enum2' END` is a syntax error?

Comment: @GCC404 The `IF` construct in Postgres should not end in `END`, but in `END IF` (see, e.g., [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)).